# Samsung Note use pen to draw sketch

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, canvas

I'm developing a webportal and I would to make a webpage that support pen touch to draw sketch directly in the browser. 
I thought about Canvas and Javascript or JQuery with php to store the image on the webserver. and I tested few examples that I found online without success.
Some examples works better than other. Opera probably is more complete to manage canvas than Chrome but the problem is always to exclude the finger touch if I'm using the pen.

Anyone have idea or suggestion about drawing with pen in a browser with a mobile device that support pen gestures (like Samsung Note or similar)?

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery events:

Ontouchstart -> You should start a timer here.

Ontouchmove -> Gives you the x and y value of the movement in px.

Ontouchend -> If very short and you have not moved an x amount of pixels in horizontal or vertical directions, it is a click. You can also sync the changes with your db here.

Those are just one of the many things you can do with the three touch events.